# Signaling BPM process from PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, jbpm, business-process-management

I am fairly new to BPM world. So i might miss basic parts of the topic, so forgive me if I do so.

What I need to do is , trigger/signal/request ( I don't know the best verb:) ) a BPM process from PL/SQL code. So my broadest guess is, this should be over an http request, most probably a web service request.

I use jBPM as my BPM engine, but it is not a must, I can use any option which is easier to work on my scenario.

Any advice on where to start.

Answer (score 2):

You may also look into UTL_DBWS, an Oracle utility package for calling (or creating) web services.

Look [HERE](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/utl_dbws10g.php) and [HERE](http://steveracanovic.blogspot.com/2008/10/using-utldbws-package-to-call-web.html) for an example of its use.

Another possibility is to create an external procedure (Java perhaps) and handle the call details there.

Finally, if the service is a more old school tcp service (probably not), look at [utl_tcp](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_tcp.htm) (I've used this with success in projects in the past, but not as easy to use as calling an xml service, and some security issues to workthrough)

Answer (score 1):

The UTL_HTTP package contains procedures to send and process HTTP requests from within a PL/SQL package. Here's a sample:

```
declare
    v_request UTL_HTTP.REQ;
    v_response UTL_HTTP.RESP;
    v_value VARCHAR2(1024);
begin
    v_request := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST('http://my.hostname.com/wsendpoint');
    v_response := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(v_req);
    LOOP
        UTL_HTTP.READ_LINE(v_response, v_value, TRUE);
        DQMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_value);
    END LOOP;
    UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(resp);
end;
```

Documentation: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96612/u_http.htm